# Tuple vs TypeTuple in D

Tags: d

What is the difference between Tuple and TypeTuple?  I've looked at sample code in the library, but they look similar.  How do I decide which to use?  and is there a good reason why Tuple is in std.typecons but TypeTuple is in std.typetuple?

Comment: Note that these are library based solutions for special purposes.
They are based on D's builtin tuple concept: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/tuple.html

Comment: @Trass3r so you are saying there are 3 types of Tuples in D?

Comment: No I just remarked the *language* only has one notion of tuples.
Tuple and TypeTuple you mentioned are library-based.

btw, original tuples can be "created" with 'template DTuple(T...) {alias T DTuple;}'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Tuple` is a *data type*, consisting of a collection of fields that you specify.

A `TypeTuple` is simply "a bunch of things" that the compiler knows about *at compile time*; it has no existence at run time.

(Contrary to its name, a `TypeTuple` can hold pretty much *anything* -- not just types!)

Comment: I feel your answer and Michal's should be combined into one.

Answer (score 3):

tuple [std.typecons](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_typecons.html) normal ordinary tuple of values.

typetuple in [std.typetuple](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_typetuple.html) is tuple of types. It can be used at compile time like in this example function, where it limits allowed types for funciton to int, long and double only.

```
void foo (T) (T arg) {
    static assert staticIndexOf!(T,TypeTuple!(int, long, double)) != -1, 
        T.stringof ~" is not allowed as argument for foo");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tuple is a collection of variables (like a struct) while TypeTuple is a collection of type which you can use in template checks

```
Tuple!(int,"index",real,"value") var;
```

defines a variable with var.index a int and var.value a real

a TypeTuple is used when you want to examine whether the instantiations of your templates use the correct types